# What file type are Elden Ring saves?

Tags: elden-ring

Elden Ring deleted my character and I need to access a backup that I deleted. I know how to use photorec, but I'd like to avoid grabbing everything and the kitchen sink. What filetype are Elden Ring saves as could be identified by Photorec?

Answer (score 1):

They are of the type `ER0000.sl2`.

Source: [PCGamingWiki](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Elden_Ring#Save_game_data_location)

Comment: What you gave is a filename. The extension is *.sl2. I'm not sure what type it is, but most likely a binary file, or a text file. (And yes, I'm being pedantic)

Comment: That's not a file type. The file type as reported by the "file" program is "data", but that just feels like a catchall